# Parse specific data from JSON

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have a JSON file with lots of data, and I want to keep only specific data.

I thought reading the file, get all the data I want and save as a new JSON.

The JSON is like this:

```
{
    "event": [
        {
            "date": "2019-01-01",
            "location": "world",
            "url": "www.com",
            "comments": "null",
            "country": "china",
            "genre": "blues"
        },
        {
            "date": "2000-01-01",
            "location": "street x",
            "url": "www.cn",
            "comments": "null",
            "country":"turkey",
            "genre": "reds"
        },
        {...
```

and I want it to be like this (with just date and url from each event.

```
{
    "event": [
        {
            "date": "2019-01-01",
            "url": "www.com"
        },
        {
            "date": "2000-01-01",
            "url": "www.cn"
        },
        {...
```

I can open the JSON and read from it using

```
with open('xx.json') as f:
   data = json.load(f)
   data2=data["events"]["date"]
```

But I still need to understand how to save the data I want in a new JSON keeping it's structure

Comment: your JSON is incomplete

Comment: Partial JSON can be found here https://pastebin.com/TYaAX1Jb

Answer (score 0):

You can use loop comprehension to loop over the events in and return a dictionary containing only the keys that you want.

```
data = { "event": [
{
    "date": "2019-01-01",
    "location": "world",
    "url": "www.com",
    "comments": None,
    "country": "china",
    "genre": "blues",
},
{
    "date": "2000-01-01",
    "location": "street x",
    "url": "www.cn",
    "comments": None,
    "country" :"turkey",
    "genre":"reds",
}
]}

# List comprehension
data["event"] = [{"date": x["date"], "url": x["url"]} for x in data["event"]]
```

Alternatively, you can map a function over the events list

```
keys_to_keep = ["date", "url"]
def subset_dict(d):
    return {x: d[x] for x in keys_to_keep}

data["event"] = list(map(subset_dict, data["event"]))
```